# How to configure org-mode to respect system-specific default applications for external links?

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode I can define external links for example as

```
[[file+sys:path/to/document.pdf]]
```

The file document.pdf is then opened with an external pdf viewer. The [org-mode documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/External-links.html) claims that this command "open[s] via OS, like double-click".

There is, however, a difference to "double-click", as I find that the system-specific default applications (for documents, websites, videos, etc.) are not respected in my setup; On Ubuntu 12.04 the default application for webpages was set to Firefox and only through org-mode local .html files are still openend with Chromium.

How do I configure org-mode to respect my default application settings?

Answer (score 9):

Here are my settings:

```
(setq org-file-apps
      '((auto-mode . emacs)
        ("\\.x?html?\\'" . "firefox %s")
        ("\\.pdf\\'" . "evince \"%s\"")
        ("\\.pdf::\\([0-9]+\\)\\'" . "evince \"%s\" -p %1")
        ("\\.pdf.xoj" . "xournal %s")))
```

Comment: Helpful, although the question asks how to make `org-mode` respect the system defaults.  This version would require us to set the defaults manually.

Comment: True, but the system defaults have a wide meaning.
For instance I'm on Ubuntu, but I have to use `~/.mailcap` to make Emacs use `vlc`,
instead of Ubuntu's system defaults tools.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a Linux desktop environment, chances are that it is using xdg-utils. See [this blog post](http://jordiinglada.net/wp/2014/10/29/xdg-open-or-computer-do-what-i-mean-3/).

Therefore, you may do this:

```
(setq org-file-apps
      '((auto-mode . emacs)
        ("\\.x?html?\\'" . "xdg-open %s")
        ("\\.pdf\\'" . "xdg-ope, \"%s\"")
        ("\\.pdf::\\([0-9]+\\)\\'" . "xdg-open \"%s\" -p %1")
        ("\\.pdf.xoj" . "xournal %s")))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of utility vars defined in later versions of org-mode:

```
org-file-apps-defaults-gnu
org-file-apps-default-macosx
org-file-apps-default-windowsnt
```

that should set up reasonable defaults for those environments.

Use them like this:

```
(setq org-file-apps org-file-apps-defaults-macosx)
```

Answer (score 0):

`C-h describe-variable  org-file-apps-macos`

Copy default application settings, then add your own.

My Own config is  (".png" . "open %s")

```lisp
(setq org-file-apps-macos '((remote . emacs)
                            (system . "open %s")
                            ("ps.gz" . "gv %s")
                            ("eps.gz" . "gv %s")
                            ("dvi" . "xdvi %s")
                            ("fig" . "xfig %s")
                            (t . "open %s")
                            (".png" . "open %s")))
```