# Open link of file in org mode with its defalut application rather than within spacemacs

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

really new to `spacemacs`, I want to open a link (which is a file stored somewhere on my computer and the full path is used) inserted into `org-mode` file of `spacemacs` with the default application of such file, say excel, rather than within `spacemacs`. I searched up online, it seems like below is the solution:
`(setq org-file-apps '("\\.xlsx\\'" . "excel %s"))`,but this throw out the error :

`wrong type argument: listp "excel $s"`.

See these links for your reference and any helpful suggestion is deeply appreciated.

I'm on the latest develop branch of `spacsmacs`, if this is of any use.

[link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763804/org-mode-does-not-open-pdfs-in-evince-even-when-org-file-apps-is-seemingly-prope), [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834633/how-do-i-make-org-mode-open-pdf-files-in-evince), [link_3](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2856/how-to-configure-org-mode-to-respect-system-specific-default-applications-for-ex)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says that `org-file-apps` should be a list of cons cells but you have supplied a single cell instead.  Solution: one more set of parens:

```
(setq org-file-apps '(("\\.xlsx\\'" . "excel %s")))
```

You now have a list containing a single cons cell and `org-file-apps` should be happy.

Comment: In the buffer, the linked `.xlsx` file still opened in another buffer, but in exported `html`, it will download the linked file.